# The image of a Riemannian submanifold under a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

> Let $\Sigma$ be a compact submanifold of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, let $h$ be the induced metric on $\Sigma$, and let $\Phi:M\to M$ be a diffeomorphism. $h_\Phi$ will denote the induced metric on the image $\Phi(\Sigma)$, pulled back to $\Sigma$ via $\Phi$.

What is the $h_\Phi$ really? I know $\Phi(\Sigma)$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ with the property that $\Phi$ maps $\Sigma$ diffeomorphically onto $\Phi(\Sigma)$, which begs a question:do the Riemannian metrics on $\Phi(\Sigma)$ induced respectively by the inclusion $\iota|_{\Phi(\Sigma)}:\Phi(\Sigma)\hookrightarrow M$ and the restriction $\Phi|_\Sigma$ coincide? I supposed that $h_\Phi$ is the Riemannian metric induced by $\iota|_{\Phi(\Sigma)}$ and tried to show that
$$\Phi|_\Sigma^*h_\Phi=h$$
but didn't find a way. The following is as far as I can go now:
$$\Phi|_\Sigma^*h_\Phi=\Phi|_\Sigma^*(\iota_{\Phi(\Sigma)}^*g)=(\iota_{\Phi(\Sigma)}\circ\Phi|_\Sigma)^*g=???=\iota_\Sigma^*g=h$$
$\iota_\Sigma$ is the inclusion $\Sigma\hookrightarrow M$. Thanks for help.

**Edit.** I think the author was trying to say
$$h_\Phi=(\Phi|_\Sigma^{-1})^*h.$$
That way, we would have
$$h=\Phi|_\Sigma^*h_\Phi.$$
This is pretty much the scenario described in the quote.

Comment: These two metrics will almost never coincide: think for instance of a circle inside the Euclidean plane and let $\Phi$ be any diffeomorphism stretching the plane along the $x$-axis while keeping the $y$-axis unchanged; then the circle will become some figure more resembling an ellipse. Aren't you actually thinking of an isometry of $(M,g)$ ? By the way, some parts of your question are a bit confuse. maybe you should try and rewrite it in a clearer way!

Comment: @DryBones Thank you. I just want to figure out what the quoted statement is trying to say. Otherwise, I wouldn't succeed in figuring out the discussions presented later by the textbook author.

Answer (score 2):

$\Phi$ being a diffeomorphism $M\to M$, it induces a diffeomorphism from $\Sigma$ to $\Phi(\Sigma)$.
Note that $\Phi(\Sigma)$ is a submanifold of $(M,g)$, so it has an induced metric $g|_{\Phi(\Sigma)}$.
You can pull it back on $\Sigma$ by $\Phi$, yielding $h_{\Phi} = \Phi|_{\Sigma}^*( g|_{\Phi(\Sigma)})$.
All these complicated notations to just talk about the following:
$$
\forall p \in \Sigma, \forall u,v \in T_p\Sigma,\quad (h_{\Phi})(u,v) = g(d\Phi(p)u,d\Phi(p)v).
$$

Comment: Thank you, but isn't $h$ defined on $\Sigma$? Why did you write $(M,h)$ instead of $(M,g)$?

Comment: @Wombat You're right, I misread the question and thought $h$ was the ambient metric. I edited

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Can I ask you one more question? Why did $h_\Phi$ act on tangent vectors to $\Sigma$ rather than those to $\Phi(\Sigma)$?